# PHP, вложенные массивы и JSON

Tags: php, массивы, json

Имеется массив, который нужно отдавать по *JSON*. Но в массиве есть вложенные массивы и это создаёт проблему.

Простой пример:

```
<?php 
echo "234";
$parametrs = array (
 "123"=> "qwe23423",
 "qwe"=> "asdasdasdasd"
);
$result = json_encode($parametrs);
echo $result;
?>
```

Вывод:

```
234{"123":"qwe23423","qwe":"asdasdasdasd"}
```

А вот если есть вложенный массив, то не работает:

```
<?php 
echo "234";
$parametrs = array (
 "123"=> "qwe23423",
 "qwe"=> "asdasdasdasd",
 "arr"-> array {
     "qaz"=>234,
     "sdf"=>"123wqax"
 }
);
$result = json_encode($parametrs);
echo $result;
?>
```

А вывода нет.

В итоге невозможно получить массив при помощи *JSON*.

Как правильно преобразовать такой массив в *JSON*?

Или: как такой массив передать без *JSON* в *Javascript*? (`var arr = eval($php_arr)` — не работает).

---- Добавил ----
https://yadi.sk/d/0YjrnGSSiMGeZ - вот ссылка на весь код. Ваш подправленный работает, мой - нет. Можете подсказать почему?

Comment: А код именно из примера? `"arr"-> array` - невалидная в php конструкция

Comment: Да и массив не `array {...}`, а `array(...)` должен быть, исправил эти ошибки и все сразу выводиться стало

Comment: нет,  это ошибка. , там должно быть =>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BOPOH, вам правильно сказал. Должно быть так:

```
<?php

echo "234";

$parametrs = array (
 "123" => "qwe23423",
 "qwe" => "asdasdasdasd",
 "arr" => array (
     "qaz" => 234,
     "sdf" => "123wqax"
 )
);

$result = json_encode($parametrs);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Вот реальный код
<?php 
$parametrs = array (
  "filials" => array(
  "19" =>  array(
   "id"  =>  19,
   "phone" =>  array(
    "main" => "111-11-11",
    "phones" =>  array(
     "1" =>  "222-22-22",
     "2" =>  "333-33-33"
    ),
   ),
   "city"  =>  "Москва",
   "preftovar" => "pechat1",
   "tovary"  =>  array(
    "pechat1"  =>  array (
     "nametovar"  =>  "С автоматической оснасткой COLOP R40",
     "material"  =>  "резина",
     "osnastka" => "автоматическая",
     "maker" => "Colop",
     
    )
   )
  ) 
    )
);
$result = json_encode($parametrs); 
echo $result;
?>

Comment: Весь не влез. Не хватает длины. потому и кидал простой пример

Comment: Ну ваш пример у меня тоже нормально парсится (если там несколько ошибок исправить, вроде на 40 и 74 строчке запятых нет). Единственное - вместо русских букв `null`, если кодировка не `utf8`.

Comment: Сравните ваш кусок кода в вопросе после "А вот если есть вложенный массив, то не работает:" с моим вариантом и вы поймете какие символы были заменены.

Comment: Странно, у меня ни в одном браузере не отображается ничего. просто пустой вывод. Ошибок апач не даёт...

Comment: Откройте лог ошибок сервера error.log или включите вывод всех ошибок в браузер.

Comment: error.log чистый, на этот файл не ругается.
Даже не знаю что сказать. Скопировал содержимое массива в работающий пример из ветки - заработало. Может где-то с кодировкой что-то не так?

Comment: Да, по ходу дело именно в кодировке. В работающем примере UTF, в не работающем CP-1251

Comment: В общем разобрался. json_encode работает только с UTF, потому любая альтернативная кодировкаи и упс...
Всем спасибо за помощь и участие!